# Generated ids in ORMLite

Tags: java, database, ormlite

I've got problem with my database. I'm downloading data from API with specific Ids. I want this ids to stay in my database so I could use them in the future in the app. I read in docs that I should add `allowGeneratedIdInsert = true` but it doesn't work - I'm still getting 0,1,and so on in the database as ids after `dao.create(...)`. Could you please check my code and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

**Here's my model:**

```
@DatabaseField(id = true, columnName = "id", allowGeneratedIdInsert = true)
private int id;
```

**Creating record :**

```
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
   if(isChecked) {
      try {
         final Dao<Concert, Integer> concertDao = getHelper().getConcertDao();
         concertDao.create(concertList.get(position));
      } catch (SQLException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: If you are storing your entities with an `id` then you don't need `allowGeneratedIdInsert`.  You just want `id = true`.  Can you be more explicit about what the id values are when you insert them and what they are in the database?

Comment: I'm downloading object from API with id f.e. 4432 and when I save it to the database it is 1. I have cleared cache and now have problem with "no such column concert_id" - I dont have that column , I created that field yesterday to check if I can have two id fields - id and id_concerts (with data from API) but now it's gone. Strange ...

Answer (score 1):

From [documentation for `allowGeneratedIdInsert`](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/field/DatabaseField.html#allowGeneratedIdInsert()):

> This only works if the database supports this behavior and if `generatedId()` is also true for the field.

And by default `generatedId` is `false`.

```
@DatabaseField(columnName = "id", generatedId = true, allowGeneratedIdInsert = true)
private int id;
```

Also as you can read:

> If the field is null or 0 then the id will be generated. This is useful when you have a table where items sometimes have IDs and sometimes need them generated.

Are you sure that you want this behavior? If your id's are already generated on back-end so you probably just don't need `allowGeneratedIdInsert` and `generatedId` they both false by default.

Comment: Thanks for response. I found the information in the documentation, however it doesn't work when I set as : @DatabaseField( columnName = "id") . I've tried to create another field - concert_id , but still the same - I get 0,1,2 in the database :/

Comment: And did you try with both generatedId = true, allowGeneratedIdInsert = true?

Comment: Yes, nothing changes :/

Comment: Did you reinstall you app after that changes? Is it android application?